# How to get this Ruby Thread to run right?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, sockets, loops, client

So I'm trying to figure out how to use threads.  I am trying to get hello world to output "Hello world!" 5 times, because I need to use a loop in my threads.

Here's what I've tried.  The first example outputs "Hello world!" once only. Make sure to look at the third code bit too...

```
thread1 = Thread.new do
    5.times do
        puts "Hello world!"
        puts
    end
end
puts "And here's me calling thread"

thread1
```

And this doesn't output anything except "here's me calling..."

```
def system_pause
    5.times do
        puts "Hello world!"
        puts
    end
end

server = MockServerClass.new(2012)

puts "And here's me calling thread1:"

thread1 = Thread.new{system_paue()}
thread1
```

And THIS one does execute, but NOT infinitely.  I NEED to use a thread to continuously accept input from a server, so I need to figure out how threads and looping works.

```
thread1 = Thread.new do
    while true
        puts "I am a little butterfly!"
        puts
    end
end
puts "And here's me calling thread1:"
```

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Keep in mind that this won't run simultaneously in MRI.

Comment: What do you mean?  And what's MRI?

Comment: It's a reference implementation of Ruby. The one you're most probably using. The reason for this is that it simply doesn't support multithreading because of Global Interpreter Lock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put `.join` after the block of all the sub-threads. Runninng a sub-thread means it will be running on its own, independently of the timing of the main thread, so the main thread will finish without waiting for the sub-threads to finish, and you would not see the results of the sub-threads unless you make the main thread wait for them, which can be done by `Thread#join`.

Comment: So does this mean that my program can't go past the thread until it finishes if I join it?  Will it still execute ***in tandem*** with the rest of my program?

Comment: You can assign variables to all your threads like `t1`, t2`, etc, and put `join` on all off them at the very end of your whole program.